# php session not saving after $_post

Tags: php, session, postback

I am experiencing issues with session where if i put the following code on a page the counter will increment by one every time i reload the page.

```
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
else
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
```

if i put the above code in an if statement where it only runs when you hit a button and display the number in the session the session is always empty.

Could there be a php.ini issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you starting the session using `session_start()` ?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code. It's hard to tell from just this info. php.ini seems unlikely to be involved, as far as I can see.

Comment: below is a very simplistic version of what is going on
session_start();

if($_POST["btnSubmit"]){
 
 $_SESSION["views"]++;
 
}


echo "VIEWS: ".$_SESSION["views"];




<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Update" />
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Your session could not be initiated. Check for tmp directory if server can write (many session issues are related with full disk!)

Comment: just check the tmp directory where the sessions are saved and the folder has the correct permissions and is only 7% full

Answer (score 0):

Also check php.ini to make sure session.auto_start=1 and for the code...

```
//debug your session
```

`echo"<!--".session_id()."-->";`

```
//update the views
```

`array_key_exists('views',$_SESSION)?$_SESSION['views']++:$_SESSION['views']=1;`

Comment: you'll want to remove the debugging once you ironed out the problem, but this way you can check to see if you HAVE a session but it's not the SAME session...

Comment: hi if i display the session id on the page load and then display what the session id is on the post back they are both the same. I have also looped through the session variables to see what keys i have and any session that is created (attempted) in the post back still isnt saved.

Comment: I have also check the php ini settings and the session.auto_start was set to 0 so i have changed that and still experience the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();  

if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views']++;
else
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
```